# SSCollectionView margin / spacing

Tags: iphone, ios, sstoolkit

I am using SSCollectionView to display images but the default spacing is too much. When I change the size of the item it just displays them larger with the same size and less items are shown be row. I tried to find the documentation for this but no luck.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at the documentation right now (first result on google). [Link](http://sstoolk.it/documentation/Classes/SSCollectionView)

Have you tried modifying `rowSpacing` or `minimumColumnSpacing`?

Comment: Well....that's embarrassing. I don't know how I missed something so obvious. Thanks.